# Python: Differences between Anaconda and SciPy. Can I install both? Can I include SciPy in Anaconda?

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I so far mainly coded with CAS like Mathematica or Maple, and only did a little bit of Python so far. I installed Anaconda, mainly because I knew the Spyder front-end from a few years ago, which I really liked.

Now I learned about a SciPy ecosystem, which contains packages which are probably more suited to my needs. However I am not sure how exactly SciPy compares to Anaconda.

For instance:

• Does it come with its own front-end, like Anaconda comes with Spyder, or is it "just" a collection of packages along with a Python installation, without own front-end, etc.?

• If it is a comparable ecosystem, can I install both, Anaconda and SciPy on my system (Mac OS), or will they conflict?

• I saw that there is also a SciPy package to download for Anaconda. Would I just have the same functionality with that package in Anaconda, as I would have by downloading a SciPy distribution? Or would it be recommendable to download SciPy separately? Also: Is SciPy perhaps already installed with Anaconda by default? If so, how can I check it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I would think that all these questions can be answered by consulting the documentation for SciPy and Anaconda. Is that not the case? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anaconda is a package manager. Scipy is a package. you can have Anaconda installed manage your environments and install packages with it. To instal Scipy in anaconda you can simply type: `conda install -c anaconda scipy`

Comment: _Anaconda is a package manager._ Incorrect. _To instal Scipy in anaconda you can simply type_ Also incorrect, and misleading. That is installing the scipy package from the anaconda channel using Conda.

Comment: Brief
conda is both a command line tool, and a python package.
Anaconda installer = Python + conda + meta package anaconda
meta Python pkg anaconda = about 160 other Python packages for daily use in data science

Anaconda installer = Miniconda installer + conda install anaconda

Detail
conda is an environment manager and a package manager. It means the tool itself. conda makes it possible to

Comment: install package with conda install flake8
create an environment with any version of Python with conda create -n myenv python=3.6
conda is not a binary command, is a Python package. To make conda work, you have to create a Python environment and install package conda into it. This is where Anaconda installer and Miniconda installer comes in.

Installer Minoconda installs a Python and the package conda. Installer Anaconda not only does what Miniconda does, it also install a meta Python package named anaconda for you.